# How express $\lim_{m \to \infty} {1 \over m} \sum_{n = 1}^{m} \sin {n \over m} x$ as an integral?

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, definite-integrals

It appears to converge. Here's a plot for $m = 8$:

[image: plot of the titular sum when m = 8]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $\frac1m\sum_{n=1}^m\sin(nx/m)$ is the Riemann sum of the integral $\int_0^1 \sin(xt)\,dt=\frac{1-\cos(x)}{x}$